# Where ARC public key is stored?

Tags: domain-name-system, public-key, dmarc

Where ARC public key is stored? For DKIM it is [selector]._domainkey.example.org. But for ARC? Is it the same as DKIM and holds in TXT query for domain mentioned above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from IETF (this is subject to change):
"

> **5.3.1. Namespace**
>
> All ARC-Seal keys are stored in the same subdomain as DKIM keys
> [RFC6376]: “_domainkey”. Given an ARC-Seal field with a “d=” tag of
> “example.com” and an “s=” tag of “foo.bar”, the DNS query will be for
> “foo.bar._domainkey.example.com”.

Source: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-andersen-arc-01.html

This is the only information I can find regarding ARC. This is not a standard yet and is still only on draft (which means that it is not sure at all if this is going to be implemented).

I can recommend you to read the above link

Good to read, because this is more up-to-date:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dmarc-arc-usage-02